# Customized datagridview Rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image: Sample]

Check the above picture. I need to know how to include a picture in a datagridview textbox row.

I would also like to know if we can add text in it and so that the picture has a click event too.

Can someone explain to me how to achieve this type of datagridview row?

From the picture you can see that it doesn't consume space for a datagridview in advance. When the row is added the datagridview size increases. How do I achieve this?

Comment: One solution is to use the CellPainting event of the DataGridView to "paint" the cell and eventually copy image to the Cell graphics. For the click issue: As the Click event doesn't provide the cursor location at click time, you will need to implement the KeyDown event to store the cursor location. Depending to Cursor location, you do the appropriate action. May you clarify the issue related to "datagridview size increase" ?

Comment: you can create your own custom grid using `TableLayoutPanel`